# Will the growth rate of a unbounded function affected by subtracting a bounded function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f(x)$ be a non-negative function with $x\geq0$, and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\infty$. Now introduce $g(x)\geq0$, with $g(x)<M$ for some $M>0$. Is the growth rate of $f(x)$ different from growth rate of $|f(x)-g(x)|$? According to what I know, we can use big O notation to describe the growth rate of functions, so $|F(x)|$ is $O(|G(x)|)$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}<\infty$. So this question is basically asking if $f(x)$ is $O(h(x))$, will $|f(x)-g(x)|$ be $O(h(x))$ as well.

Here is my attempt. Let $f(x)$ is $O(h(x))$, then $h(x)$ must be also unbounded. Consider $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{h(x)}$, which is greater than or equal to $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{f(x)}{h(x)}-\frac{g(x)}{h(x)})$. The first term is finite by assumption, the second term is greater than or equal to $-\frac{M}{h(x)}$, which goes to zero. So the whole limit is finite. So the growth rate is unchanged.

Comment: Yes and the proof is very simple. Please show your attempt.

Comment: Prove that $f+o(f)=O(f)$.